# Search with smooth scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, scroll

Can anyone show me how to add a smooth scroll to this script.

[search and scroll](http://imspiration.net/so/searchText.htm)

js

```
    function searchText() {
        console.log($(window).scrollTop($("p:contains('" + $("#search-input").val() + "'):eq(0):last").offset().top));
    }
```

many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this out:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/

using the animate() function of jQuery

EDIT:

just use this function instead:

```
function searchText() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("p:contains('" + $("#search-input").val() + "'):eq(0):last").offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```